# framer-motion in nextjs won't animate a margin of -100vh to 0vh but animates 0vh to 100vh just fine

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I am trying to animate a navbar to open and close. I have a larger container that animates by changing height, and I want to slide down this inner container while it animates its height. However, the animation only works one way, so when the navbar is closing it animates as if it's sliding up but when it's opening there is no animation.

```
const innerVariants = {
    open: {
        marginTop: "0",
    },
    closed: {
        marginTop: "-100vh",
    },
};
```

```
<motion.div
    initial={false}
    variants={innerVariants}
    animate={isOpen ? "open" : "closed"}
    transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
    style={{ height: "100vh" }}
>
</motion.div>
```

Error Message:

```
You are trying to animate marginTop from "-100vh" to "0vh". -100vh is not an animatable value - to enable this animation set -100vh to a value animatable to 0vh via the `style` property.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without seeing more code but you may need to use the window height as a number instead of 100vh as a string.

Something like this:

```
  const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

  const innerVariants = {
    open: {
      marginTop: 0,
      transition: {
        duration: 0.5
      }
    },
    closed: {
      marginTop: -windowHeight,
      transition: {
        duration: 0.5
      }
    }
  };
```

here's a working code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-framer-motion-in-nextjs-wont-animate-a-margin-of-100vh-to-0vh-but-animates-0vh-eiduvq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It works!!! I changed the original margin height from a string "0" to the number 0. Turns out it also works with view height but the original margin-top has to be a number, not a string. Thanks for the solution!!!